# Sphinx space within list because of a figure tag

Tags: list, space, python-sphinx

I made a documentation with sphinx and now I have only 2 broken lists before it is done.
I included ordered lists and within them I added some figure tags. Because of the limited space on the site, sphinx is putting the picture on the next site of the guide and pushes up the whole content which is normally below the picture.

Here the problem:

At the position, where the picture normally should be within the ordered list, it leaves a little space between the lines which I cant get out of there.

Here the first screenshot:

[image: See space between number 3 and 4]

Here my Syntax: (please ignore the `.. screenshot:` tag... its pointless for you, I think)

[image: My Code]

Here the copy of the syntax, had to delete the # of the ordered list, because thy bolded the whole line:

---

```
#. Click the ``Edit`` link on the right side of the relevant product’s row.

#. Click the ``Prices`` tab in the left navigation panel. See :num:`Figure #prices-options`.

    .. _prices-options:

    .. figure:: special_price_and_product_group_price/screenshots/prices_options.png

        Prices Options

    .. screenshot::

         Given I log in as admin user "admin" identified by "admin"
         Given I am on |backend|
         When I click on Catalog
         When I click on Manage Products
         When I click on Edit
         When I click on Prices
         Then take screenshot of the full Prices tab and save "prices_options.png"

#. In the ``Special Price`` field, enter the special price.

#. Optionally, set ``Special Price From / To Date``. If you leave these fields blank, the special price is applied
   immediately and applies until removed on the same page.
```

---

Is there a possibility to tell sphinx to start up a new chapter or line at a new page without manually put line breaks within the syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `.. _prices-options:`, `.. figure::`, `.. screenshot::` sections and see if one of them triggers the extra spacing.

If there's no obvious culprit, check the HTML syntax for the list - is it two different lists, or different styling applied to the 2nd list item?  I have seen cases where adding a paragraph to a list item results in every list item getting formatted with wider margins (including those that were single lines, with no children).  That is a `ReStructuredText` action, not specifically from `sphinx`.

Comment: First I tried to remove the figure tag now, because it has extra margins arround too, but it didn't work.
In the next step I tried to folloow your answer and deleted the space between the figure block and the list items. I couldn't believe that the spaces are gone, **BUT** now there is a different problem, because the first list item is bolded without these spaces.
I m a little bit confused, because there is no syntax to bold this line, I just removed the spaces.